# javascript - multiple settimeouts in loop

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I want to read a file, do some stuff, check action mode.

If mode = STOP then delay processing until mode != STOP, otherwise repeat entire process.

I want it to keep delaying until mode changes.

The code below results in an infinite loop & browser crash:

```
function fnIterateGeocode(addressVariations) {

    // read a file & do some stuff  

    // check for delay
    fnDelay();

   // if not end of file then Iterate
   if (nextRecord.EOF != 'Y') {
        setTimeout(function(){                      
            fnIterateGeocode(addressVariations);                        
        }
        , 5000);
    }


    // if mode = STOP, then delay for 5 seconds and check again     

    function fnDelay(){
        if(mode == 'STOP'){
                setTimeout(function(){                                                      
                }
                , 5000);
                fnDelay();
        }
        return;
    }           

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've put the call back to `fnDelay` in the wrong place:

```
function fnDelay(){
    if(mode == 'STOP'){
            setTimeout(function(){
                // It should be here
            }
            , 5000);
            fnDelay(); // Not here
    }
    return;
}
```

The way your code is current written is indeed an infinite loop (well, it would be if you didn't run out of stack space), because `fnDelay` always calls itself immediately.

Comment: I want it to keep looping in a delay until mode changes to 'GO'.

Comment: Your suggestion won't achieve anything either, simply call fnDelay (which does nothing) in it's own little loop every 5 seconds. Effectively the same as `setInterval(function(){},5000)`

Comment: @beeglebug: I didn't debug the *rest* of it for him, just addressed the infinite loop. I assumed there was code that wasn't shown.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you fully understand asynchronous code.

There is no way to 'delay' javascript in the way you are trying (like `wait`, or `sleep` in other languages). The call to `setTimeout` does not halt execution at that point for 5 seconds.

Try thinking of setTimeout as a request to put the passed in function into a queue to be called at some point in the future. Once done, the script will immediately proceed to the next line of code as with any other function call.

In your example, something like the following would make more sense:

```
function fnDelay(){
    if(mode != 'STOP'){ fnIterateGeocode(); }
    else { setTimeout(fnDelay,5000);
}
```

This will call itself every 5 seconds as long as `mode == 'STOP'`, as soon as it doesn't, it will call `fnIterateGeocode`.